# How to avoid repeatedly recalculating a function that is used multiple times in another function

Tags: function-construction

Example as following

```
g[x_]:=NIntegate[......];

f[x_]:=g[x]^2+g[x];
```

I need to have define f[x] through g[x], Does mathmetica NIntegrate g[x] twice when calculating f[x]?
How to rewrite it to reduce calculation?
My idea is to give the value of g[x] at some x to a variable and use it in f[x].

```
value=g[x];
f[x_]=value^2+value;
```

The value giving should be done inside f[x_]. How to build up the function definition in mathematica in such way?

**Update:**

After a bit of study myself, the new code I write is:

```
g[x_] := NIntegate[......];
f[x_] = #^2 + # &[g[x]]
```

The function definition gives correct answer. Does it calculate g[x] once or twice in this way?

Comment: Yes, Mathematica calls `g[x]` twice, since you called it twice. Why not use `=` instead of `:=` and this way, it will integrate once? But it is better to make a complete working small example, showing the actually integration you are doing. This way, one does not have to guess.

Comment: I usually do `With[{value = g[x]}, (*some expression with value *)]` but I'm not sure how well this may work in NIntegrate

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the situations that `With` is designed to handle.

```
g[x_] := NIntegrate[u/(1 + u), {u, 0, x}]
f[x_] := With[{u = g[x]}, u^2 + u]
```

Then

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/8617#8617) (*Memoization/Caching*)

When you define `g` as

```
g[x_]:=g[x]=<definition of g in terms of x>
```

you can make use of the fact that *Mathematica* 'remembers' the values of `g` that are already evaluated.

In the context of the question, the output of a-possibly-computationally costly function like `NIntegrate` will be evaluated only *once* for a given input.

In the following code `RandomReal` will be used as a substitute for the output of some costly function like `NIntegrate` and `Pause` is used to simulate the time consuming nature of `g`.

```
g[x_]:=g[x]=(Pause[1];RandomReal[])
f[x_]:=g[x]^2+g[x]
```

Now, the first time eg `f[2]` is executed, *Mathematica* will evaluate `g[2]` and then assign the value of `g[2]^+g[2]` to `f[2]`.

The next time *Mathematica* encounters `f[2]`, it will no longer need to *evaluate* the costly `g[2]` again because it will already have  a rule saved that associates the expression`g[2]` with the value that was calculated, the first time `g[2]` was encountered.

In short, the costly function `g` will be calculated once, only the first time *Mathematica* encounters `f[value]`. In all subsequent evaluations where `f[value]` is relevant, there will be no need to re-evaluate the costly `g[value]`.